# Serve Webpack from a virtual directory

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am building all my files int a 'dist' folder.

```
Dist

->index.html

->bundle.js
```

I have the configuration set to run off a specific port that I need.

```
{   
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9004,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    watch: true,
}
```

I've tried adding

```
proxy: {
    "/virtual-directory-name-here": {
        "target": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 9004
        }
    }
}
```

Under devServer, but with no luck. I understand you can add `publicPath` under output, but I don't necessarily need the files served with the virtual directory in it. I just want it to act like an IIS virtual directory.

My ultimate goal is to serve all files from the `dist` folder at http://localhost:9004/virtual-directory-name-here

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this, too.
Found a solution using the proxy option for devServer:

```
proxy: {
    "/virtual-folder": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:9004",
        pathRewrite: {"^/virtual-folder" : ""},
    }
},
```

Also, if someone uses https for localhost, may need to add to the config:

```
secure: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this configuration:

```
export = {
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/virtual-directory-name-here/",
        openPage: "virtual-directory-name-here/",
    },
};
```

Note that `publicPath` has a preceding slash but `openPage` does not. This seems to be important.